# Decimal places in NumericUpDown control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am sorry if this has been answered before. I searched around and couldn't find a suitable answer.

I have a numericupdowncontrol that takes user input. Right now I have set decimalPlaces property set to 2.
If user enters 1.23, it stays correct. However if user enters 1.2, then it displays 1.20. That is not what I want. It should display 1.2 and not 1.20. Is there a way to do this?
If user enters 1, then it should be 1 and not 1.00. How do do this?

Thanks much!

Comment: You could simply strip out the 0s after the TextHasChanged event is fired. Simple and easy. You'll need a bit more logical to handle the decimal depending which side the numbers fall on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I was confused whether I need to write custom code or some existing numeric control property would do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind customizing your `NumericUpDown`, you can do this which is very easy, short and reliable:

```
//You can use this class instead of the standard NumericUpDown
public class CustomNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    //Override this to format the displayed text
    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        Text = Value.ToString("0." + new string('#', DecimalPlaces));
    }
}
```

Comment: When having a number without decimals as value/text, I cant type a point/comma at the end. I would have to do so before a number so it gets displayed and then change the decimals. Maybe this answer is pointing into the right way, but its not solving the problem. Example: Try typing `2,` or `2.` with the goal appending decimals to `2`. **It wont work.**

Comment: @C4ud3x I don't understand what you meant at all. I agree that if you type something like `2,456` when the current culture uses `,` as the decimal point, then it won't work. But if so we have a simpler fix by just provide the current culture as the second argument passed in `ToString`.

Comment: @KingKing Simple try: If in your culture its `.`, then just go ahead and try to type `1.2` into the `numericUpDown` with your solution. Is it working? For me not. `UpdateEditText()` is firing on **EVERY** keypress. Your solution is formatting the text on **EVERY** keypress by using the value. When typing `1.` the `Value` is `1` and gets saved into `Text`. You cant write a point. It gets converted with the keypress and never shows up.

Comment: @C4ud3x it's working of course. Not sure why it does not work for you. I thought you had some special requirement different from what the OP wanted  but looks like it's the same. And the OP accepted this answer meaning there is nothing wrong (except the problem of specific culture as I mentioned).

Comment: @C4ud3x we almost need the `Value` property of the `NumericUpDown`, not its `Text` property. So I think you have some special requirement when you need the exact Text the user types in. This answer was not wrong and satisfied the OP. Of course for your ***own*** requirement, you need to modify the code. The most important thing here is the usage of the method `UpdateEditText` - which is not easy to be found out and take benefit.

Comment: @C4ud3x also I've just checked it, the `UpdateEditText()` is not called ***EVERY*** keypress like you said, you can try printing something in that method (or set break point), run a simple form and typing the text to see it in action. I'm not sure if there is some option changing that behavior (it was a long time since I've worked with Winforms). It's also strange that the code is not working for you, for me the `UpdateEditText` is fired only when the focus is switched to another control or when you press Enter.

Comment: @C4ud3x you must access the `Value` property of the NumericUpDown inside some keystroke-related event handler (such as `KeyPress` event handler, ...). I've tried that scenario and yes then the problem will occur. That's your own problem and in fact I had no time thinking about that scenario when answering this question. It's of course some kind of bug but just easy to understand and fix. You seem to did it yourself.